# What do the readonly attributes in diskpart really mean?

Tags: read-only, diskpart

I am wondering exactly what the meaning is of the "Read-only" disk and volume attributes that you can twiddle in diskpart on Windows 7.  I am trying to set up an external USB drive as an installation medium for my own software, so I'd like to protect it against casual or inadvertent changes by users who it is given to, so they don't screw up the installation files they might need in the future.

From what I can tell by experimentation with diskpart, the volume read-only attribute is actually stored on the physical disk somewhere, because I can set it and it shows up when I take the drive to another machine.  This is great because my users can't (easily) change any of the files on the volume, or format it from Windows explorer.

However, the disk read-only attribute seems to be just an aspect of how the current machine is accessing the drive.  When I set it I can no longer delete the volume in the disk via Disk Management, but when I take the drive to another machine, the attribute is no longer set and in Disk Management I can delete the volume on the disk.  I guess I'm not that worried about my users doing that, but I am annoyed that I don't understand what these attributes are really doing.

Another thing that I don't understand is that the "volume" read-only attribute actually seems to be global to the disk - if I have two volumes on the disk, and I set the readonly flag on one of them, then it gets set on the other one too.  ?!?

I have the feeling I'm not searching for the right docs - all I'm finding is diskpart docs that give the syntax for twiddling these attributes, not what they really mean.  Any pointers would be very welcome!

Thanks,

Asa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer:

`Attributes  DISK  [set | clear] READONLY` stores the attribute **in the Windows registry**, not on the physical disk. This means **it is only valid for the currenlty running Windows installation and it won't be carried, set and enforced on other OSes**.

`Attributes VOLUME [set | clear] READONLY` stores the attribute **on the physical disk**. This means **it WILL be carried, set and enforced also onto other OSes, including Linux** (I had to manually remount the disk in rw mode, plus it didn't touched the stored attribute, so I had to manually remove it in Windows).

**BE CAREFUL with administrative access, though**:
while the `DISK` attribute prevents **ALL writes on the entire disk** (i.e. both the volume(s) filesystem and the partition table), the `VOLUME` attribute prevents writing **ONLY to the volume(s) filesystem**, leaving the partition table STILL writable (i.e. you can still delete a read-only volume).

---

## Long answer:

### Attributes `DISK` [set | clear] READONLY

The attribute is stored in the value named `"Attribute"`, located at the registry subkey `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\*\Disk*\Device Parameters\Partmgr`, where `*` is the disk's enumerated and installed device node (look in Device Properties in Disk Management).

It's a bitmask value, and the `readonly` attribute is Bit #1 (Bit #0 is for online/offline disk status), so setting `readonly` on an online disk will change the value from `0` to `2`, but setting it on an offline disk will change the value from `1` to `3`.

**Advantages:**
The disk is **entirely** read-only: all write attempts will guarantee to **FAIL**, **including its partition table** (e.g. deleting/creating volumes, changing the disk ID and so on), plus the status will be clearly visible in Disk Management.

**Disadvantages:**
It is valid only for the currently running Windows installation while its enumeration device node is the same (no guarantee for removable drives). The disk will be in read-write mode again if it is connected to another computer or its device node changes for any reason, e.g. it is connected to another bus, port or hub (especially USB) or it is uninstalled and reinstalled in Device Manager.

### Attributes `VOLUME` [set | clear] READONLY

The attribute is **physically stored on disk**, but the difference is dependent by the underlying partition scheme (MBR or GPT).

**On `GPT` disks:**
The attribute is stored in the "Attributes" field of the volume's partition table entry, and it is valid **ONLY for that volume** (as declared in the `diskpart` help description).

**On `MBR` disks:**
The attribute is stored at **offset 0x400h** (or sector #2 on a 512-byte logically formatted disk) as a "short version" of a GPT entry where only the `Type GUID` and `Attributes` field are used for a total of 0x18h bytes, and it is valid **FOR ALL VOLUMES** (as declared in the `diskpart` help description).

Here below a sample hexadecimal output and its structure:

```
   Hex Offset    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
   0000000400   A2 A0 D0 EB E5 B9 33 44 87 C0 68 B6 B7 26 99 C7
   0000000410   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10
```

- 0x400: 128-bit GUID `Type GUID`, with value `EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7` (i.e. the Microsoft *Basic Data Partition* Type GUID);
- 0x410: 64-bit integer `Attributes`, with value `0x1000000000000000` (i.e. bit `#60` set).

In the same way, it is possible to set the `shadowcopy` (bit `#61`), `hidden` (bits `#62`) and `nodefaultdriveletter` (bits `#63`) attributes.

**Advantages:**
The attribute is preserved when the disk is connected to other systems, e.g. Linux, which preserves it even if the volume is (re)mounted in rw mode.

**Disadvantages:**
The attribute is not visible in Disk Management but only within `diskpart`, plus:

On `GPT` disks:

- attributes applies ONLY to the selected volume (but this is expected behavior);
- it does not prevent the read-only volume to be deleted (but if it is deleted, the attribute is automatically cleared, because its associated GPT entry is entirely zeroed out).

On `MBR` disks:

- attributes applies to ALL volumes on the disk, due to no other way to set attributes on MBR (and the consequent on-disk attribute structure);
- volumes can be still deleted (for unknown reason, AFAIK);
- the attribute is NOT cleared if one or more or all volumes are deleted (the only way to safely clear it is by executing `attributes VOLUME CLEAR readonly` at the `diskpart` prompt);
- new volumes can still be created, but cannot be formatted (because it is a write operation).

---

This is my simple point of view, but the reason why the volume attributes are applied to ALL VOLUMES on MBR disks can be:

1. No more available places in the MBR sector, 'cause "Boot Indicator" flag refuses any value other 0x80 or 0x00 (or the boot sequence will go crazy) and the "Optional" bytes located at offset 0x1BC (444) are declared as "reserved" (despite some bits of that 16-bit field could be used);
2. Windows shares the same Type GUID for all filesystems in a partition, so setting that Type GUID it means "for all data volumes" (other Type GUIDs like the Recovery partition will not receive a Diskpart "volume" entry, only a "partition" one).

Thank God, He really helped me trying to put all the pieces of the puzzle together (including this better total rewrite).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently digging around volume attributes because Vista installation fails without using official Setup, by deploying an image using imagex and bcdboot.

I can't figure out where diskpart saves the information about attributes, most likely on the disk because (nodefaultdriveletter) is also applied after restarting; also when booting to an offline system.

And yes, **diskpart is applying volume attributes always to all volumes** on the selected disk. **The behavior of `attributes volume` is not the expected, and it is nowhere documented**. Occurs on all versions including Win8's build 9200.

The readonly attribute is only a hint, it doesn't prevent one from writing on the disk.

To hide a volume from Windows, use `remove`, but that information is saved to `HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices` (so only applied to the current running system), or you are required to use `set id=`, NTFS default id is 07, try 17 or 27. There is a [List of partition identifiers for PCs](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html), to decide what you like. FAT32 identifiers does Windows like to also identify as NTFS, without mounting them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On MBR disks, setting any volume to RO affects all volumes.
Diskpart doesn't allow you to set the RO attribute on Removable disks (like Removable flash drives) so Removable USB flash drives cannot be write-protected when moved to another system.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying this but realized when I set a flash drive with attribute disk set readonly command, the flash drive becomes readonly only for that pc where I did that setting. on other PCs I can still write to that specific flash drive.
What I found is to edit ownership of flash drive. I edit entry for everone to read only and added my user as full control. So this works for me now, unless anyone who knows how to edit ownership, this works greater than diskpart attribute setting.